# How to identify a message size from device to IoT hub in azure when using AMQP protocol?

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

Currently we have a device connected to IoT hub instance. We need to measure a particular message size sent from device to IoT hub.

Message sent is in *Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message* format.
It's like as below

```
Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message msg = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None)));
```

How to measure the message size in Bytes?

Comment: Is this for debugging purposes or message decoding purposes?

Comment: It's for debugging purpose. I have to check compression ratio for different message size. It's a test activity

Comment: I don't think you can find out the size, without receiving it.   Because it could be a stream, and a stream doesn't have a length, therefore there isn't a property to get the length.

Comment: @Neil From this web page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling#other-limits IoT hub's Device-to-cloud messaging has Maximum message size 256 KB. How to verify the maximum size? I have control from device side messaging.

Comment: If you have control of sending messages, why not store the body length in the message properties dictionary?

Comment: The original message size I can store and print in logs. But my interest is to figure out the outgoing message size after compression. Because compression is done in a different component which I don't have access to.

Answer (score 1):

A message size, be it any protocol (AMQP, MQTT, or HTTPS) cannot go beyond 256 KB for Device to Cloud messaging. For the calculation of daily quota for each pricing tier (other than free tier), messages are calculated in 4 KB size for each packet per second. If the size is bigger than 4 KB, a new message packet is created. These packets are counted against the pricing tier you had selected for your IoT hub. There can be stream of messages, but each message cannot go beyond 256 KB. In order to identify the message size, you can deploy the Stream Analytics. Refer to the below articles.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs